# install multi-node cassandra in windows

Tags: cassandra

Is there any detail step-by-step document to address the multi-node cassandra installation in Windows?   I read some documents/blogs and tried on Window7 workstations/Windows2008 servers but not be able to establish connection from the 2nd node to the 1st node.

Answer (score 2):

When I was setting up my first cluster on windows I found this [blogpost](http://kimola.com/articles/cassandra-installation-on-windows-platform) to be excellent. It covers many aspects of the setup including:

- Firewall / Networking issues.
- Running Cassandra as a service.
- Monitoring and maintenance.

If you want to create a complete setup with using just cassandra have a look at [**this blog**](http://zeshanfarooqi.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/configuring-multi-node-cassandra-cluster-on-windows/).

But to setup a multi-node cluster, you basically need to have the [correct ports open](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/firewall_ref) on your servers. When it comes to configuration you are basically going to have identical **cassandra.yaml** configs accross all your nodes, with the same seeds list, and the only two fields need to be changed are the `listen_address` and possibly `rpc_address` (although you could just listen an all interfaces for the `rpc_address` by setting it to:

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Datastax tutorial `Page not found`.

Comment: Again :) Datastax tutorial `Page not found`

Comment: @VasiliyBorovyak I understand the frustration. The link's been removed now. Some digging through yielded [this blog post](http://kimola.com/articles/cassandra-installation-on-windows-platform) which goes over quite a bit of what the DS blog covered.